# Change Localhost Front Page

Tags: localhost

I don't know what's the correct way to put this, but here's what I would like to do.

I have localhost set up in `/var/www/` and there's an `index.php` file in the folder serving as the index page for the localhost. 
I have drupal set up in `/var/www/drupal/`, is there a way to point the front page to drupal folder when I go to localhost in web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting this into /var/www/index.php:

```
<?php
   header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/drupal/' ) ;
?>
```

Comment: on second thoughts, it probably doesn't need the domain name -- the other answer is better as it won't break if you change the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: put HTTP redirection inside `index.php`:

```
<? Header('Location: drupal/'); ?>
```